# How secure are protected routes in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, authorization

I just started working on a simple website using Reactjs where you have to login to view certain pages. This is my first project using Reactjs and thus I do not feel as confident in react in comparison to more traditional approaches such as PHP-based websites and security measures.

Recently I was researching how to create pages in Reactjs that are only accessible when you are logged in. And I found [this approach](https://dev.to/mychal/protected-routes-with-react-function-components-dh) where the basic idea is the following:

```
if(isAuthorized()){
    // show protected route
} else {
    // redirect to landing page
}
```

where `isAuthorized()` could be just a `state` (as presented in the post) or (as I would probably do it) a function which always asks the server "Hey, am I still logged in?" and to use the response to ether show the page or redirect to the landing page.

But now comes my question: In a standard PHP-approach you would have to ask the server for permission each time you want to access a website and the sever can simply refuse to respond with the protected website potentially containing top secret information. But when you use the proposed code, the check `isAuthorized()` runs on the users machine, right? And thus, all the information (login page, landing page AND the protected pages) must already be in the users memory somewhere, right? So to check whether the user is logged in or not doesn't matter for attackers as they get all the information as soon as they load the login page. And even if that would be save, the attacker would just change the return value of `isAuthorized()` because all the code is running on their machine.

It might be that I am still not understanding the basic mechanisms of Reactjs and maybe all my thoughts are nonsense. If this is the case, I'd love to get a better understanding of Reactjs. If I did understand everything correctly than maybe there is a more secure approach to achieve a simple login system in Reactjs

Comment: The important part is that your server doesn't send any sensitive data to the client without appropriate authorisation. If the user "hacks" around the app and discovers some templates and components for authorised users… well, that doesn't matter much. But the *data* filled into those templates must be fetched from the server using authentication.

Comment: That's correct, the user has access to the full React app. It's running on their machine, after all. But you don't trust the client, you don't include anything actually secret in the app content, you expose it from an API with authentication. All the attacker gets is an empty "frame" and a network tab full of failing requests.

Comment: But still the "hacker" whould have access to the basic structure of the website, right? And thus he knows what a authorized person could do. (Maybe an admin can change someone elses password). And thus he can figure out what command he has to send to the server to do so. Even if this required authentication, I can also imagine this to be a back door, is some whay?

Comment: If your "security" can be compromised by a hacker knowing what commands they *could* send, then your security is non-existent. Trying to hide what commands are available is *security through obscurity*, which never lasts long. Your server needs to reject requests if the user is not properly authenticated, period. Then it doesn't matter what an attacker might or mightn't know.

Comment: Okay, thank you all for the input. That helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you store an accessToken in the localStorage you could post the access token to the server and verify it, and then use the approach you showed. But something like this:

```
const verify = (accessToken) => {
  axios.post('verfiyurl', accessToken).then((res)=>{
    return res.verfied // res.verfied is true or false
  })
}

if(verify(accessToken)){
  return null
}
```

However as long as you have authenticating on the backend, which you should. The approach you posted is more than enough.

Comment: You wouldn't want to do this check for every single route. As long as the client holds *an access token*, it should assume it is authenticated unless proven otherwise (e.g. until it makes a request to the server which gets rejected). If you're using JWTs or something of the sort, the client can even inspect the token to determine whether it has expired or not.

Comment: You are right, as long as he is authenticating on the backend the first approach should be good.